# MVC. Как вызвать Представление с ошибкой если не нашелся контроллер?

Tags: php, mvc

Есть такой код файла **`Route.php:`**

```html
<?php

class Route
{
 static function Run()
 {
  $ControllerName = 'Main';
  $ActionName = 'Index';

  $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  if (!empty($routes[1])) $ControllerName = $routes[1];
  if (!empty($routes[2])) $ActionName = $routes[2];

  $ModelName = 'Model'.$ControllerName;
  $ControllerName = 'Controller'.$ControllerName;
  $ActionName = 'Action'.$ActionName;

  $ModelFile = $ModelName.'.php';
  $ModelPath = "app/Models/".$ModelFile;
  if (file_exists($ModelPath)) include $ModelPath;

  $ControllerFile = $ControllerName.'.php';
  $ControllerPath = "app/Controllers/".$ControllerFile;
  if (file_exists($ControllerPath)) include $ControllerPath;
  else
  {
   Route::ErrorPage404();
   //debug_print_backtrace();
  }

  $Controller = new $ControllerName; //$ControllerName;
  $Action = $ActionName;

  if (method_exists($Controller, $Action)) $Controller->$Action();
  else
  {
   Route::ErrorPage404();
   //debug_print_backtrace();
  } 
 }

 // 404
 function ErrorPage404()
 {
  // вызвать страницу ошибки
 }
}
```

---

И сам **`класс контроллер:`**

```html
<?php

class Controller
{ 
 public $model;
 public $view;
 
 function __construct()
 {
  $this->view = new View();
 }

 // Дія action по стандарту
 function ActionIndex()
 {

 }
}
```

---

И **`класс контроллер ошибки:`**

```html
<?php 

class Controller404 extends Controller
{
 function ActionIndex()
 {
  $this->view->create('404View.php');
 }
}
```

---

Вопрос следующий: **Как мне вызвать представление с ошибкой?**

---

(*Это был один из примеров с Хабра, но и тот не рабочий :DDD;* Поскольку я далеко не профессионал в **MVC**, хочу спросить еще один нюанс).

```
$Controller = new $ControllerName;
```

*Что означает следующая строка? Я конечно могу только догадываться, что она означает. Но не могу понять, каким боком данные переходят в Классы контроллеров? Как раз с помощью этой строки?*

Comment: `профессионал в MVC` - таких профессионалов  природе не существует.

Comment: @Visman, я образно)

Comment: У вас там после первого вызова `Route::ErrorPage404();` должен стоять return, иначе php дойдёт до `$Controller = new $ControllerName;` и будет Fatal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать ошибку, можно сделать так:

```
public static function ErrorPage404()
{
    require_once 'app/Controllers/Controller404.php';

    $controller = new Controller404();
    $controller->IndexAction();
}
```

Здесь класс `Controller404` должен находится в файле `app/Controllers/Controller404.php`

```
$Controller = new $ControllerName;
```

Здесь в переменной `$ControllerName` хранится название класса. Как я понял, для "главной страницы" в переменной `$ControllerName` будет значение `ControllerMain`. Класс `ControllerMain` должен находится в файле `app/Controllers/ControllerMain.php`

Comment: А как можно вызвать `404page`  через `View`?

Comment: Мы фактически обсуждаем не MVC, а три php-файла, при чём явно должен быть ещё один файл `View.php` с классом `View`. Как он работает и что из себя представляют шаблоны - не известно. Более точного ответа чем `как-нибудь - это же php` дать не получится. А если мы всё таки обсуждаем MVC, то нет такого понятия как `404page`. И ответ - никак

Comment: в `View.php` у меня класс `View` и публичная функция создания этого вида.`function create($ContentView, $Data = null) include "app/Views/".$this->TemplateView;`, и `$this->TemplateView` равно пути общего шаблона.

Comment: Действительно, я же забыл об подключении `if (file_exists($ControllerPath)) include $ControllerPath;`, вот по-этому я и не мог догадаться, что не так)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
$Controller = new $ControllerName;
```

Создается новый экземпляр $ControllerName, обычно пишут так $User=new User(); то есть User() это класс, который содержит в себе методы, с которыми он работает, и мы наследуем все эти методы в переменную $User. То есть таких экземпляров может быть сколько угодно, $User, $Guest, $Admin и т.д.

А по коду, приведенному Вами: какие ошибки сыпятся?

Comment: Ошибок то нету, просто я хотел сделать при указании неверного `url` выводить страницу ошибок.

Comment: Вы не знаете как это сделать, потому что: 1. Вы не знаете как вызвать контроллер из другого контроллера. 2. Не можете понять логику, где лучше разместить класс ошибки, в каждом контроллере или в отдельном. 3. Вы не знаете как вывести вьюшку?

Comment: в том то й дело, что на этом примере пытаюсь разобраться. И честно говоря, я новичок в этом. Читал разные статьи, кое-что запомнил и понял, а кое-что нет. Даже если я догадаюсь как вывести "Вьюшку", то мне надо быть уверенным, что я сделал правильно, по-этому й спрашиваю. А опыт работы с ООП очень маленький.

Comment: Есть пример **вызова** вьюхи из любого контроллера? Потому что сейчас мы обсуждаем абстрактные вещи

Comment: например главная страница, делаю так: `class ControllerMain extends Controller
{
 function ActionIndex() $this->view->create('MainView.php');
}`. Но это прописано в самом контроллере. Ну в общем, Алексей все сделал так, как я и думал. Просто у меня выдавало ошибко о не существовании контроллера из-за строки: `require_once 'app/Controllers/Controller404.php';`